# android.os.AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR

Tags: android, android-asynctask, versions

```
09-22 15:18:06.343: E/AndroidRuntime(374): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.os.AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR
```

This error occurs when doing this code

```
    SetHoliday holi = new SetHoliday();// asynchronous task

        SetAbsent abs = new SetAbsent(); // asynchronous task


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            holi.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, Selected);
            abs.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, Selected);

        } else {
            holi.execute(Selected);
            abs.execute(Selected);
        }
```

I want to execute the asynchronous  task parallely in api level below 11
But Threadpoolexecuter is not found in this apis
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

The default executor for an asynctask changed from parallel to serial in API 11, so a regular `execute()` will run the asynctasks in parallel in API levels below 11.

You may want to switch the `<=` to `>=` to make the code work.

Comment: i tried this but still remaining the same error     java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.os.AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR